# How do I dynamically generate sections in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, dynamic-visualforce

[image: VF page with 3 sections]

The objective is to have numberOfSections variable in the controller and then dynamically generate these sections on the vf page with the same format. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct a list:

```
public String[] sectionNames { get; set; }
public myClass() {
  sectionNames = new String[] { 'Section 1','Section 2','Section 3' };
}
```

Then you can iterate over it:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:repeat value="{!sectionNames}" var="sectionName">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!sectionName}">
      Content would be here
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

You cannot directly use the `numberOfSections` variable to construct the table, as Visualforce does not support something like `while(index < numberOfSections)`, so you must already have the list predefined in your controller somewhere.

Comment: @sfdcfoc thanks. I used a similar implementation!